# C# XNA always IsRunningSlowly

Tags: c#, performance, xna, rendering

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace proj
{
    public class game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        public static SpriteBatch sprite_batch;
        public static Texture2D texture;

        public game()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 300;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 300;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            sprite_batch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("a"); // 1 x 1, white
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime game_time)
        {
            base.Update(game_time);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
            sprite_batch.Begin();
            if (gameTime.IsRunningSlowly)
            {
                sprite_batch.Draw(texture,
                    new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 200), Color.OrangeRed);
            }
            sprite_batch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

For me the orange square is visible nearly all the time, however almost nothing is happening at all.

60 Update nothing and 60 Draw nothing, making 120 almost empty function calls that should occur and they have a whole second to do this in for the program to not be "running slowly", yet `gameTime.IsRunningSlowly` returns `True` nearly all the time.

I'm sure my computer is fast enough to handle this better, whats going on? I need to be able to use gameTime.IsRunningSlowly, I can't if it's not working properly.

Comment: That's not the standard base game template, do you have something else going on wrapping the code? I opened up a brand new game project and copied the actual code pieces you have in the Initialize and Draw and I don't get the same experience. In fact, if I put a break point on the line that would draw the Orange square, it never got hit in letting it fun for 5 minutes for me.

Comment: I'm not having any issues now and I've not changed any of the code. This is frustrating and quite nice at the same time.

Comment: Maybe your virus protection was running earlier and hogging your system resources? Something like that could cause your system to start running slowly and as a result cause the game to run slowly.

Comment: Maybe. My system is set up for things like that not to occur automatically but to prompt me so I can accept when I'm not doing anything else, not to use virtual memory because it has loads of real memory etc... I don't think it was the rest of the system. Perhaps something about how I'm initialising things creates an intermittent fault. I can't see anything wrong with how I am initialising things though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do nothing. The problem will clear up all by itself magically!

Seriously though, IsRunningSlowly shouldn't be lying to you. In a basic game project it should never be returning True unless system resources are scarce. If it's returning True all the time then I'd recommend taking a look and seeing what other processes are running.

IsRunningSlowly is one of the XNA framework features that has been there from the start and while there is potential you've found some edge case that exposed some strange bug with it reporting incorrectly, it is unlikely.

I'd recommend re-starting the PC and then trying again. If the problem persists, you're going to have to start examining what other processes are using system resources at start-up or evaluating your current hardware setup (and you shouldn't need much for an empty game project to run at 60 FPS, the XNA default)

Comment: Seems so :¬) Perhaps Microsoft rolled out a stealth update while I was away :¬P

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might Andras :) It was just hard to resist since it  was the correct answer in this case!

Comment: There', I made the answer less frivolous.

Comment: @George I deleted the comment in the end because of the +1 and the tick (the great thing about SO - you can't argue with the community)!  You know what - this might be the first and probably only time a 'do nothing' answer is actually correct - good on you!  I can hear Jon Skeet's knees knocking! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to game() constructor. This should make the game call updates as frequent as it can.

```
                 this.IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want it to update as much as it can. I'm happy with the 60(F, U)PS. Also, the issue it seems to somehow have fixed itself anyway having spent ages on it earler, despite not changing anything. See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.  The game is running slow, but is virtually not using the pc's resources
I have noticed in my code that I was being dragged down by the game starting.  It would fall a second behind and stay there.  This is very hard to debug, because anything like a break point triggers the game running slowly field.

I eventually tracked the problem down by using an external timer and comparing it to the in game timer.  I had results like

in game/ real time
1/2
5/6
10/11

so the game lost a second on start, but then ran fine.

It is most likely that there is a correct way to start the game and load resources, that would avoid this problem